# Using mySQL variables in subqueries

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use user defined variables to limit the results of a subquery, in order to get the difference between two timestamps in some analytics data.  The code I am working with is as follows:

```
SELECT  @visitID := `s`.`visit_id` AS `visit_id`,                             # Get the visit ID and assign to a variable
        @dt :=      `s`.`dt` AS `visit`,                                      # Get the timestamp of the visit and assign to a variable
                    `tmp`.`dt` AS `next-visit`                                # Get the 'next visit' timestamp which should be returned by the subquery

FROM `wp_slim_stats` AS `s`                                                   # From the main table...

LEFT JOIN (SELECT   `s`.`visit_id`,                                           # Start the subquery 
                    MIN(`s`.`dt`) as `dt`                                     # Get the lowest timestamp returned
               FROM `wp_slim_stats` AS `s`                                    # ...from the same table
               WHERE    `s`.`visit_id` = @visitID                             # Visit ID should be the same as the row the main query is working on
                   AND  `s`.`dt` > @dt                                        # Timestamp should be HIGHER than the row we are working on
               LIMIT 0, 1) as `tmp` ON `tmp`.`visit_id` = `s`.`visit_id`      # Join on visit_id

WHERE `s`.`resource` LIKE 'foo%'                                              # Limit all results to the page we are looking for
```

The intention is to get an individual pageview and record its visit ID and the timestamp.  The subquery should then return the *next* record from the database with the same visit ID.  I can then subtract one from the other to get the seconds spent on a page.

The problem I am running into is that the subquery seems to be re-evaluating for each row returned, and not populating the `next-visit` column until the end.  This means that all the rows returned are matched against the subquery's results for the final row, thus all `next-visit` columns are `null` apart from the final row.

The results I am looking for would be something like:

```
_________________________________________________
| visit_id     |     visit     |      next-visit|
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      1       | 123456789     |  123457890     |
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      4       | 234567890     |  234567891     |
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      6       | 345678901     |  345678902     |
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      8       | 456789012     |  456789013     |
|______________|_______________|________________|
```

But I am getting

```
_________________________________________________
| visit_id     |     visit     |      next-visit|
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      1       | 123456789     |  NULL          |
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      4       | 234567890     |  NULL          |
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      6       | 345678901     |  NULL          |
|--------------|---------------|----------------|
|      8       | 456789012     |  456789013     |
|______________|_______________|________________|
```

I am still fairly new to using variables in mySQL, particularly when assigning them dynamically.  As I mentioned, I think I am messing up the order of operations somewhere, which is causing the subquery to re-populate each row at the end.

Ideally I need to be able to do this in pure mySQL due to restrictions that from the client, so no PHP unfortunately.  Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Comment deleted to avoid misunderstanding, thanks for the tip @fancyPants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need variables here at all.

```
SELECT `s`.`visit_id` AS `visit_id`,                          
       `s`.`dt` AS `visit`,                                   
        (SELECT MIN(dt) FROM `wp_slim_stats` ws WHERE ws.visit_id = s.visit_id AND ws.dt > s.dt)
FROM `wp_slim_stats` AS `s`                                                
WHERE `s`.`resource` LIKE 'foo%'
```

And to answer why your solution doesn't work, have a look at the order of operations in a sql query:

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

Comment: Brilliant!  I have obviously over-thought this one ;)

Comment: With regard to the order of operations, how do sub-queries fit in? Would it go through the 6 stages for the main query, then the subquery, or the other way round, or process the FROMs from the each, then the WHEREs from each, and so forth?

Comment: The subquery is in the select clause of the main query, plus it's a dependant subquery (meaning it's output depends on values from the main query), so it would go through the first 5 stages of the main query, then the 6 stages of the subquery, then the last stage of main query again.

Comment: Cool, I will have a play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query you would need to run.

> select visits.visitid as vId, temp.time as tTime, visits.time as vTime
>   from visits inner join (select min(id) as firstId, visitid, time from
>   visits v1 group by visitid)temp on visits.visitid = temp.visitid where
>   id > temp.firstid group by visits.visitid;

See [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ff5d/1)